# xmlPullParser don't reach END_DOCUMENT eventType

Tags: android, android-xmlpullparser

I'm having a problem with parsing an xml file. While parsing it's reach the final end tag, but never meet the END_DOCUMENT. It seems that is an infinit loop!!! However, if I change the String result by "<foo>Hello World!</foo>", that works!!!

```
public void parseXMLData(String result) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    factory.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_DOCDECL, true);
    XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
    xpp.setInput( new StringReader ( result ) );
    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

    String prefix = null, name = null, value = null;

    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

        switch(eventType) {
        case XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT: Log.i(TAG, "end document");
        break;
        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG : Log.i(TAG, "start tag"); Log.i(TAG, xpp.getName());
        break;
        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG : Log.i(TAG,"end tag"); Log.i(TAG, "end "+xpp.getName());
        break;
        case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT : Log.i(TAG, "start document");
        break;
        case XmlPullParser.TEXT : Log.i(TAG, "text");
        break;
        case XmlPullParser.COMMENT:
        Log.i(TAG, "COMMENT");
        break;
        case XmlPullParser.DOCDECL:
        Log.i(TAG, "DOCDECL");
        break;
        case XmlPullParser.IGNORABLE_WHITESPACE:
        Log.i(TAG, "IGNORABLE_WHITESPACE");
        break;
        }
        eventType = xpp.next();
        Log.i(TAG, "next(): "+eventType);
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "Saiu do while");

    if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        Log.i(TAG, "end document");
    }


    showResults();
    //str_forecast = xpp.getText();


    Log.i(TAG, "Chamou showResults()");
    //return xpp.getText();
}
```

My XML resource is http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=455823&u=c

Thanks

Comment: Do you ever get out of the loop?

Comment: Only with the "foo" xml example.

Answer (score 1):

So what is it actually doing, running infinitely? If it's just not printing out your `Log.i()` for the `END_DOCUMENT` case, that's because you've set up your while loop to exit as soon you encounter the `END_DOCUMENT` tag.

Comment: It seems running infinitely!!, however if I change the String "result" by a simple xml hard coded, it works!! I think that the problem is in the xml source delivered by yahoo.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

eventType=xpp.next();

insteadof

eventType = xpp.nextToken();